# Bezier curve and canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

How I can draw bezier curve in canvas. I have only start point and end point. I want to draw line from start point to end point. How I can do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `Path.quadTo()` or `Path.cubicTo()` for that. Examples can be found in the SDK Examples (FingerPaint). In your case you would simply need to calculate the middle point and pass then your three points to `quadTo()`..

Some code for you:

- **(x1,y1)** and **(x3,y3)** are your starting and ending points respectively.
- create the paint object only once (e.g. in your constructor)

  ```
  Paint paint = new Paint() {
      {
          setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
          setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
          setStrokeWidth(3.0f);
          setAntiAlias(true);
      }
  };

  final Path path = new Path();
  path.moveTo(x1, y1);

  final float x2 = (x3 + x1) / 2;
  final float y2 = (y3 + y1) / 2;
  path.quadTo(x2, y2, x3, y3);
  canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  ```

Comment: can you give this for curve?

Comment: This results in a straight line, if you want a curve, then change the control point, here (x2,y2) to some thing else.
A quick example would be:-
x2 = (x3+x1)/3
y2 = (y3+y1)/3

Answer (score 5):

With [`Path`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) you can draw cubic and quadratic bezier curves. See [`cubicTo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#cubicTo%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29) and [`quadTo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#quadTo%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set color...your code is correct and change `x3,x3` to `x3,y3` in the `quadTO()`.