# Android Path bended/waved line

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have a java list with points that needs to be drawn as a path in a canvas. I would like to create something like a curved line from the point list.

An example of the line can be found here:
http://postimg.org/image/67p4ztil1/

thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked `FingerPaint` Demo in Android SDK Examples. You can use Path.quadTo() or Path.cubicTo() for that.

This may be useful for you - [Bezier curve and canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993030/bezier-curve-and-canvas).

**EDIT: Line Path: Bezier Curves**

http://rengelbert.com/blog/line-path-bezier-curves/