# make straight line curved by touching

Tags: java, android

I'm working on app that draws a straight line and the user can curve it 
(like an arc) by touching a point in that line and start moving his finger.

I was thinking of

```
drawArc ()
```

But it doesn't seem that i can change it at run-time, or even handle it.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: It seems you want a Bezier Curve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993030/bezier-curve-and-canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use a `Path` and draw a path with `canvas.drawPath(path, paint);`. You can curve ut with `path.quadTo(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)`

Comment: can you give me an example of how to use this method? thanks!